# Sorting with angularjs does not wait and goes to the next line

Tags: angularjs, arrays, sorting, angularjs-controlleras

I am implementing a table sorting in the controller and what I am doing is:

- sorting and
- with the result of the sorting slice for paging.

it looks like the code does not wait for the sorting to finish and go to the next line, how can I implement some kind of async task for sorting?

This is the code of my controller:

```
 $scope.sort = function (field) {
        $scope.sortType = field;            
        $scope.begin = 0;
        $scope.end = 10;
        var sorted = $filter('orderBy')($scope.users, field);
        $scope.filteredArray = sorted.slice($scope.begin, $scope.end);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Everything here is purely synchronous. If you think it's not, then post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. My guess is that you're sorting on a field which doect exist in the users, which causes the array to stay as it is.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will double check. In The browser when dubbuging it jumps the line...so it look something wire to me.